# Go: cannot find package "fmt" error

Tags: go

I'm trying to follow a simple `Hello, World` application in go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")
}
```

But when I build and run it, I get the following error:

```
main.go:5:2: cannot find package "fmt" in any of:
    /home/user/go/src/pkg/fmt (from $GOROOT)
    /home/user/gocode/src/fmt (from $GOPATH)
package test_program
    imports runtime: cannot find package "runtime" in any of:
    /home/user/go/src/pkg/runtime (from $GOROOT)
    /home/user/gocode/src/runtime (from $GOPATH)
```

Here is the ouput of `go env`:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/user/gocode"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/home/user/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/home/user/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Comment: Where is fmt/fmt.go located?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just did `apt-get install golang` and then set my GOPATH

Answer (score 88, accepted):

[Unset GOROOT](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really) - the go tools know where they are supposed to be and you rarely need to set it.

You've set it to `/home/user/go` and unless you build go in there that is unlikely to be the right place to find the fmt package.

Comment: How do I unset GOROOT?

Comment: To unset GOROOT for the current session, type "unset GOROOT". However, you probably want to unset it permanently; in this case, just delete the line setting the variable from the config file in which it is set (e.g., /etc/profile or ~/.bash_profile)

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that you *should* set GOROOT if you install Go in a non-standard location - it's probably best to read the whole [blog post](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really) to understand what the "standard location" is, since it depends on the way you installed Go.

Answer (score 11):

Don't use `apt-get` for installing [go](/questions/tagged/go), just download the [binaries](http://golang.org/doc/install#tarball) and extract them to your home (or any) directory.

To get the `go tool` available in your terminal, you have to add the `export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin` line to your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I agree with you here, but you should explain *why* not to use apt-get: Go development is moving fast, and Linux distros are very likely to have outdated versions in their repositories.

Comment: If you want to install go from a package then I recommend [godeb](http://blog.labix.org/2013/06/15/in-flight-deb-packages-of-go) which builds a debian package from the latest binary release of go on the fly

Answer (score 2):

After failed run `go run case.go` command. I try to use apt installation in a new ubuntu 16.04 environment.

```
apt install golang
```

after this, the `go run case.go` will run as expected.

I guess the problem is **you should never set the GOROOT**.

Once you find the **GOROOT** is not something like "/usr/lib/go-{version}",

you already in the wrong situation. use `unset GOROOT` immediately. add it to `/etc/profile` or `~/profile` or `~/.bashrc` etc. for permanent effection.